# 14.04: Compiz Fusion effects are glitchy

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz, thinkpad

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my ThinkPad X220 (8 GB RAM; Intel Core i5; 512 GB SSD) and some compiz fusion effects (Skydome, 3D Windows, Freely Transformable Windows) are now glitchy.

I once installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my old laptop (Compaq Pressario, 4 GB RAM, Intel Pentium; 125 GB HDD) and it worked perfectly there. How come these effects work on a more than 5 year old system but not on a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Unity team doesn't care about Compiz effects, and Unity's window decorator (introduced in 14.04) just breaks them. If you disable Unity plugin, most of these will work correctly.